# Reference a UITableView inside a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I have `UICollectionView` whose cells have a `UITableView` inside it.
How do I reference the `UITableView` inside it without creating a custom class of the `UICollectionViewCell` with a referencing outlet for the `UITableView`?

The reason why I don't want to create a new class for the `UICollectionViewCell` is because it would have no other purpose than to reference the `UITableView`.

Something like this:

```
UICollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

//Need to reference the UITableView (obviously this doesn't work)
UITableView *tableView = collectionViewCell.tableView;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

i Hav'nt tried this with UITableview..but the cell has a property [cell.contentView viewWithTag:someValue] just set the tag of table view u added to someValue and later u can refernece it.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, but `viewWithTag` returns a `UIView`, not a `TableView`.

Comment: Type Cast the returned view like this (UITableview *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:sometag]

Comment: UITableView is a subclass of UIView. So a UIView might as well be a UITableView. See my answer to learn how to check if a UIView is a UITableView. It's called Introspection.

Answer (score 0):

you could loop through the subviews

```
for(UIView *view in collectionViewCell.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]])
    {
        UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)view;
    }
}
```